# Live templates over files in PhpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm, live-templates

What I am looking for is something like a "live template over files in PhpStorm".

Assume you have a very well known coding task. For example add a new field in your CMS backend. In that task you know exactly what you have to code, in which files and so on. Actually you just copy and paste already implemented fields and edit some words in your code. With PhpStorm Live Templates you can create a snippet for one file.

What I am looking for is something like a "live template over files in PhpStorm". So the Live Template goes in the specific files automatically and adds the pieces of code on the right place.

In case of Live Templates are not a proper approach, is that even possible in any other way in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 0):

I think, if I well understand, you can do it by customizing your Code templates.

Go to Settings, Editor -> File and Code Templates. Then you can put code which be automaticaly added when you create a PHP Class or javascript or anything else you'll customize.

Comment: I like to add code in php and javascript AT THE SAME TIME  with just ONE live template. I cant see any possibility in phpstorm.

Comment: @ChristianMichael That's not possible.